# create a macro to delete cell content in a column that meets certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello can someone help me.
I have three columns and I want to search each column and delete content if it meets 
certain criteria.

Column B delete only cells with names
Columns C delete only cells with the word tray and a number
Column F delete only cells with * followed by four 0000 then ends with *
This is what I came up with but it isn’t working and I am not sure what to do. I have searched and searched. How do I do this thanks?

column B name column  cell format FN,LN  Clear any names from row 16 to lastrow. Some 'row may have dates and time I don’t want to touch those

column C range format Tray 226985 clear the content of any rows in that column with the word tray followed by a number to the lastrow

column F range format *000000226985* begins with a * then four 0000 and ends with a * delete cell content with that format to the lastrow

```
Sub Macro1()

Range(b1, b65536).Value = ("*,*").clearcontent
Range(c1, c65536).Value = tray(*).clearcontent
Range(f1, f65536).Value = ("*0000*").clearcontent

End Sub
```

Comment: if you try to record macro doing what you want you'll be quite close. If you then encounter any problem put your improved code here and we will try to help you...

Comment: i got a compile error expected end of statement and it stops at .clearcontent. I am not sure whats wrongs

Comment: your code even doesn't resemble vba code, unfortunatelly. I regard your try but you will have much better results if you just start  macro recording from scratch, than record any single step you described. Next, try to analyse and return with any problem here. Anyway, do you really need VBA here, isn't just step-by-step filtering useful enough?

Comment: I have around a 1000 rows on each sheet so I wanted to do a command button to look for cells and remove content. If there is a better way I am open to learn that also. I did start out with a macro recording. I am new so I am looking under every rock to figure it out.

Comment: it has to search the columns confirm the cell content and clear the content whats a better way if not with a macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the below should complete your required task by looping through each cell in column A and checking the offset cells. I have replicated your criteria but I am not familiar with 'tray(*)', I think you may want to replace that line with something like:

```
If c.Offset(0, 2).Value Like "Tray*" Then
```

You may need to look into alternatives if it HAS to be a number after 'Tray', I'll leave it to you to get the criteria right but hopefully I have helped with the method of looping.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, c As Range

Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set rng = sh.Range("A:A")

For Each c In rng

    If c.Offset(0, 1).Value Like "*,*" Then
        c.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    End If
    If c.Offset(0, 2).Value Like tray(*) Then ' see note on replacing this line
        c.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    End If
    If c.Offset(0, 5).Value Like "*0000*" Then
        c.Offset(0, 5).ClearContents
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. i will check your code. I did the following and fell of the chair when it worked. thanks everyone

Comment: Sub Macro1()
    Range("f1:f65536").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Tray*", eplacement:="",               LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False     Range("f1:f65536").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="*0000*", Replacement:="", lookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Range("b1:b65536").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="*,*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End Sub

Comment: Hi A h, not sure why the code didn't display properly, not posted code in comments before and I thing there is a technique to it... As for your code that looks like it would serve your purpose for a simple replace, I took mine from something I wrote that deleted rows based on criteria so needed an extra level of complexity (more on top iof this also as the cells in range doesn't always work when deleting rows...)

Comment: Also, if you are happy that what you have is working for you then could you mark the question as answered. Thanks